# why isn't the CBPeripheralManagerDelegate method calling?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

why isn't the CBPeripheralManagerDelegate method callinga although i have initialized the class as 
  var bluetoothManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)

and already added BlueTooth Framework in my Bundle.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class AppSettingsViewController: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       var bluetoothManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension AppSettingsViewController : CBPeripheralManagerDelegate{


    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!) {

        if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn{

            println("broadcasting")



        }else if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOff{

            println("no bluetooth found")

        }else if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.Unauthorized {

            println("This option is not allowed by your application")

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make your `bluetoothManager` an instance variable. Currently it gets deallocated when `viewDidLoad()` finishes.

Comment: Are you sure it is not being called? You are not checking all the states in there. btw switch statement would be more appropriate there

Answer (score 2):

You have to save your `bluetoothManager` to global variable of your ViewController in order to receive call-backs.

```
class AppSettingsViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

    var bluetoothManager : CBPeripheralManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.bluetoothManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)


    }
}
```

Comment: still not calling ?? is it that, it gets called whenever there is change on the bluetooth settings ?

Comment: Are you running on a real device (iPhone 4S or later)?  You should get a call to `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState` shortly after you initialise the `CBPeripheralManager` if Bluetooth is on

Comment: I'm not sure about extension's effect, but just try to move delegate call to the  Viewcontroller but not in extension.  This call-back is called after your create (and keep reference) a CBPeripheralManager and whenever the bluetooth of your iDevice change state.

Comment: oops..i am testing it on simulator.. i thought it should call delegate..delegate is called only after state is changed of the bluetooth?

Comment: You can't test Bluetooth on a simulator - only on a real device with BLE support.  This code is working on my phone - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/1ec2077b2d868d48f337

Comment: The call-back is still called even in simulator. But you will received an Unsupported state

Comment: I updated the gist to include a switch statement for all values - unsupported is reported on the simulator

Comment: it is not the case... why this method isnot calling func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!) {